# "What do you do for fun?" auf Deutsch

Tags: english-to-german

I want to ask someone what they do in spare time (i.e. not at work). In English I would say, "What do you do for fun?"

How would I express this in German? Would it be:

Wie machst du Spaß?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Was machst Du in der Freizeit?

Was tust Du, abgesehen vom Beruf?
```

oder

```
Was sind Deine Hobbys?
```

Comment: Oder "Was hast du für Hobbies?"

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking someone what he does for fun you can ask:

Was machst du zum Spaß?

Or

Was sind deine Hobbys?

Comment: "etwas zum Spaß zun" is more like making a joke - I'd rather go for "etwas tun, um Spaß zu haben."

Comment: In regard to activities in your spare time, you don't use "Spaß" at all.

Comment: Etwas Neues gelernt. Danke!